# error C2059: syntax error : '<end Parse>'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

This is My Visual C++ Code Used for Hardware Driver But i am getting follwoing error at Compile time.

```
template<class _A, class _R>
struct unary_function {
typedef _A argument_type;
typedef _R result_type;
};
```

Comment: it actualy compiles fine on my Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Show the code, which is causing error. See the long error in output. This code you have shown is not the actual reason, how you've used is the actual source of error.

Comment: I am Visual Studio 6.0

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. Something we could copy&paste into a file, compile it, and see the error ourselves.

Comment: @SatyavanChoure: _Why_ are you using Visual Studio 6.0? That IDE and compiler _predate standard C++ itself_. They are almost TWENTY years old. They have many infamous oddities to the extent that I would be content writing off this entire question as moot and instructing you to use a compiler from _this_ millennium and century.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use identifiers beginning with an underscore and a capital, they are reserved by the implementation. Most probably `_A` or `_R` is already defined to something that does not make any sense when substituted into your code.

See : [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/3233393)

Comment: And `unary_function` has been used for `std::unary_function`.

Comment: @songyuanyao as long as there's no [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that shouldn't technically be an issue.

Comment: @Ajay can you prove it ? The snippet is perfectly valid apart from these identifiers.

Comment: I have tried this but not working in my case..Still same problem ...Same compile time error...

Comment: @SatyavanChoure no clash with `std::unary_function` either, as songyuanyao pointed out ?

Comment: Probably just a bug. VS6 predates standard C++ and has many oddities. This entire question is frankly moot.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit wow ! I knew VS6 was old, but not *that* old... Do we have a "ancient artifact crumbled upon inspection" vote-to-close reason ?

Comment: @Quentin: "Problem that can no longer be reproduced"? ;)